# inventory system: transaction-based or store quantity, update with trigger?

Tags: coldfusion, transactions, rdbms, inventory, inventory-management

How would you design the data model for an inventory management system in RDBMS?

Would you:

1. store each purchase & usage, and uses SUM() and GROUP BY to calculate the warehouse quantity on-the-fly?
2. same as 1, but consolidate the quantity daily, and use the value of the previous day?
3. quantity as an Int field, update through application layer?
4. same as 3, but make use of DB trigger?

Transaction-based inventory system seems to be superior in terms of level of details it captures, but it is harder to implement it correctly.  Performance will degrade over time.

Quantity-based inventory system seems much easier, but might need extra lockings to make sure the Qty value is ++ or -- correct.

Which one would you choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would most likely go the trigger route, and update the quantity as transactions are pushed into the database. This makes it really easy to see what the current quantity is without need of a bunch of subqueries and calculations.

If it's done in a trigger, then you can ensure that regardless of where the transaction comes from, the quantities in your stock tables will always be updated (whether there are transactions added via hard INSERTs or via the application).

If there are logging concerns, then wrap some logging into your trigger to track before/after quantities into a separate logging table.

A trigger might look like this (not tested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[OrderAdded] 
   ON  [dbo].[Orders] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DELCARE @ProductID int; DECLARE @Qty int;
    SET @ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM inserted);
    SET @Qty = (SELECT Qty FROM inserted);
    UPDATE StockTable 
    SET Stock = Stock - @Qty
    WHERE ID = @ProductID

END
```

I don't see that there would be a performance issue to worry about so long as you've got your `StockTable` properly indexed for the ID and Stock field (I'm of course making all of this up given that you didn't provide any DB information).

Comment: can you please enlighten me, how would your trigger look like? Thx

Comment: and how would you tackle the performance degrade over time? thx

Comment: Added a trigger example to my answer.

Comment: thank you Dan, but what benefit(s) does trigger bring compare to doing the -- in the application layer inside a transaction?

Comment: Which application? What if you have multiple systems hooking into the orders? If you add an order outside the application (for whatever reason), then you're going to lose that bit of stock tracking.

Answer (score 2):

You want transactional data if an audit trail is important. And, I've never seen a real system where it was't.

As far as performance is concerned I would:

1. capture a denormalized value on a periodic basis - hourly or daily for instance
2. move transactional records involved in this denormalization process to another table (i.e. from "current" to "warehouse").

Then totals would be a sum of this denormalized value and current transactions.

This approach also facilitates backups as the number of transactional records could exceed available disk space. So write out the warehouse to tape backup for instance.

Comment: awesome, I think this is the better, but more complicated solution indeed, since it's not easy to do "denormalization" in ORM.  And I need to use cfscheduler to schedule the task...

Comment: I would rely on the database task scheduler for this purpose. As for the sum, lets say you have a class called `Account` with methods `getWarehouseTotal()`, `getTransactions()` and `getTotal()`. This last method, `getTotal()`, could be a CF code only that adds `getWarehouseTotal()` and a summation of `getTransactions()` inside a loop. Not the most elegant or efficient, but easy to implement with an ORM doing the persistence.